# What is the solution to this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

[sequence.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hStGY.jpg)

So my teacher decided to give us this special challenge. (it is not homework) I have been wracking my brain for 4 days and my teacher does not want to give the answers, please help me.

EDIT

also: [A better quality of the sequence:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALNON.png)

Yes, it is a table sequences.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Math Stackexchange! As the picture in your link has pretty low quality and not that much content, it would be helpful if you could just add the sequences to your post, so it is easier and more convenient to look at them. Greetings,

Comment: thank you for your response, typing the problem made it a mess, so I made it in excel and made a screenshot of that.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit in what the excel has? It's not easy to understand the problem itself with just that table. What does each number represent in your table? So let's suppose you're trying to find some $f(x,y)$ that (using your table) verifies $f(1,1)=9,f(1,2)=6,etc.$ Is that what the problem means?

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful if you gave more context about what kind of math your teacher would use. For example, what level of education are you at? (high school, undergraduate, graduate...) You do not need to answer this question if you wish to keep that private, of course.

Comment: @IsaacRen My teacher teaches at  a university, but he said that the math was on a Collage level, he didn't specify what year.

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso I am not sure I got a few coordinates (5:2 - 3:2 - 5:1 - 2:1). And I was told to solve the entire thing.

Comment: I can see no question, no problem, just a meaningless collection of numbers without any explanation.